# How to Copy Filtered Range To Array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, copy

The purpose is to open a workbook from SharePoint, set the auto filter, copy filtered range into the existing sheet.

The two longest pieces are opening the workbook and pasting as values.

I want to store the filtered range in the array and then assign this array to the existing worksheet (instead of copy - paste).

I have another module from which I am running all the subs (this is one of them). In that module I am starting with the below.

```vb
Public Sub TurnOffFunctionality()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub OpenWorkbookWithPopulation()

strFilePath = *Path to the SharePoint*

period = 202009

file = period & "_FR05_GRIR_Population"

strFileName = file & ".xlsb"

Set wbkopen = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath & strFileName, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)

With Workbooks(file)
    .Worksheets("ERP Extract").AutoFilterMode = False
    .Worksheets("ERP Extract").Range("A1").AutoFilter
    .Worksheets("ERP Extract").Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:="Trade"
    .Worksheets("ERP Extract").Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:=">" & 90
    .Worksheets("ERP Extract").AutoFilter.Range.Copy
    cockpit = .Worksheets("Cockpit").Range("C6:C12").Value2
End With

With Workbooks("Master_Template_Working")
    .Worksheets("Aged GRNI_Pop").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Worksheets("Instructions").Range("C38:C44") = cockpit
End With

Workbooks(file).Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Worksheets("ERP Extract").AutoFilterMode = False` and `.Worksheets("ERP Extract").Range("A1").AutoFilter`. You mean : `.Worksheets("ERP Extract").Autofilter.showalldata`?

Comment: I can't see that you have turned off calculation and screenupdating. If that is the case then that will probably do some difference.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the first post.

Comment: I doubt it makes any difference but you `Set wbkopen` but you use: `With Workbooks(file)`. The more "usual" way to do it is `with wbkopen`. Apart from that. Opening and saving files takes time. Especially over network, and probably worse when it's cloud based. Only possible way I can think of to speed it up is to in workbook open, use command line or something similar to download the file async while opening the workbook. Then use the temporary workbook you downloaded as the file you open. That way the file might be faster to open and use. Why do you save file when nothing has been changed?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this way. Hmm where am I saving the file? The last action is SaveChanges:=False so I thought changes are not saved? I just need to close the workbook in this line.

Comment: You are right... My bad.

Comment: How many rows and columns are in `ERP Extract`? Approximately e.g. 10000*100? How many resulting rows are you expecting? How long does it take to open the file, how long to filter and how long to paste?

Comment: Approx 4k rows (it will vary from month to month) with 22 columns (~88 000 cells) in total. However, I only need a part of it which is ~1200 rows * 22 columns (26 400 cells).

The idea I have now is to store ERP Extract (alldata) in array, set this as a value for the destination worksheet and instead of filtering - sort the values and remove what I dont need.

Comment: My idea is: -Turn off Autofilter, -Copy the complete range into an array, -Loop the array and check columns 17, 18 for the criteria, -As criteria is found write the results to the same array, -Copy the relevant part of the array to the destination worksheet. -To define the range in the source worksheet, I would use `CurrentRegion` so if you could check if this gets all the data: `Debug.Print  Workbooks(file).Worksheets("ERP Extract").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address`. I'm short of time now, but I might do it in a couple of hours.

Comment: VBasic2008 - this sounds even better than the one I am doing now. Thank you - I would be pleased if you found some time to put this together. No rush, whenever is fine for you would be great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this (not tested):

```
With Workbooks(file)
    With .Worksheets("ERP Extract")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Dim Data As Variant
        ' If this doesn't work, use another way.
        Data = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    End With
    cockpit = .Worksheets("Cockpit").Range("C6:C12").Value2
End With

Dim ColumnsCount As Long
ColumnsCount = UBound(Data, 2)

Dim i As Long ' Source Rows Counter
Dim j As Long ' Columns Counter
Dim k As Long ' Destination Rows Counter
k = 1 ' account for headers (i = 2 To ...)

For i = 2 To UBound(Data, 1)
    If Data(i, 17) = "Trade" And Data(i, 18) > 90 Then
        k = k + 1
        For j = 1 To ColumnsCount
            Data(k, j) = Data(i, j)
        Next j
    End If
Next i

With Workbooks("Master_Template_Working")
    With .Worksheets("Aged GRNI_Pop").Range("A1")
        .Resize(k, ColumnsCount).Value = Data
    End With
    .Worksheets("Instructions").Range("C38:C44") = cockpit
End With
```

Comment: Works great! The time has been reduced by 50%. Now it takes approx. 50 sec vs 130 before. Thank you very much! Would you have also some materials where I can look for information to understand what you did here? :-)

Comment: You must understand basics about arrays since you have one of your own: `cockpit`. Do you understand `LBound` and `UBound`? Do you understand looping an array by row and by column? How about `Resize`. Tell me what you understand and I'll try to fil in some blanks. The code does exactly what I described in my long comment below your post. I'm sure that with very little effort you can identify which part of the code covers what. So maybe identify the lines of code you do not understand.